# Cassandra CQL Join queries?

Tags: cassandra, aggregate, cql

I am working in cassandra, but i have issues in queries like (group by) and aggregations (count ,max )etc. I had tried this query.

'select sip,dip,sport,dport, count(bytes) from stream_analytics1.aggregateflow2 group by sip,dip,sport,dport;'

 Can be please help how can i execute these queries in CQLSH?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MAX(), DISTINCT and group by in Cassandra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342176/max-distinct-and-group-by-in-cassandra)

Comment: @Arslan, through **CQLSH**, you can't able run aggregate quires. so,  you tried with **spark-sql scala**.

Comment: thanks for suggestion but i am working in java. Are these aggregation query supported in java?. I had find that in scala but dn't find any help in java.